# Average of Two Strings C++

Tags: c++, string, average

I have two String Max and Min that where obtained using a list of Strings by simple comparison operation.

Now, I want to use these two Strings to find like the average of this two Strings. Meaning I want to have like the middle String between these two Strings.

For example if I enter "a" and "z" the average should be "m"

Comment: What'd be the average of "asdf" and "qwerty"?

Comment: What should the average be if you enter "hello" and "goodbye"?

Comment: Yes, your questions are valid... I want to think of an average that splits the space between "hello" and "goodby" into halfs

Comment: @shaklasah: So what would that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you doing these operations on strings of same size? In this case, you can use average of the ascii of each character.

in c it will be

```
(char)((int)c1 + int(c2))/2.
```

Make sure the strings have the same case (both uppercase or both lowercase.)

Comment: This will work if the characters have values in the range 0-127, but may fail beyond that.

Answer (score -2):

returns the ASCII code of "a" and "z", averages and displays this symbol

```
string a="a";
string b="z";
int first=Convert.Toint16(a);
int second=Convert.ToInt16(b);
int average=(first+second)/2;
char c=Convert.ToChar(average);
```

Comment: This looks not a lot like C++.

Comment: @Oli ++ and # looks very similar on those newfangled windows phones.